# Minify a big TypeScript application automated

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, minify

what's the best way to minify and merge all my generated JavaScripts automated. I use Visual Studio to develop my application. I have the idea to create a script and use jsmin. But how to replace the references in my main index.html?

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--out yoursinglefile.js` parameter on tsc. This will give you a single merged JS file for all your typescript files.  e.g.:

```
tsc a.ts b.ts --out merged.js
```

Next you can minify this file using jsmin or google closure or whatever :)